# Difference between `play run` and `play akka start` commands in the Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I am a bit confused and would like to an explanation.

I am using Java Play 2 with Akka actors. I start the system by using `play run`.

However, I just saw a video that used the command:

```
play akka start
```

to start a Play framework that supports Akka. Is this required for the Play 2?

Thanks all!

Comment: Most probably you saw a log of Akka's start when used in the controller, as @szegedi pointed `play akka start` isn't a valid console's command.

Comment: BTW, just curious, could you show us that video?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Play 2.0 doesn't use akka as a command line argument as far as I know (at least its not present in sbt's help command, and I got an error trying to use it). The difference between `play run` and `play start` is the following:

`play run` - starts the application in debug mode, with automatic recompilation of classes (if they are changed and you'll refresh the browser's window, your app will be recompiled) This is for development.

`play ~run` - same as above, with that difference, the recompilation process starts as soon as changes in the files are detected (doesn't wait for browser's refresh)

`play start` - starts the application in production mode, no recompiling, much better performance, this is intended for everyday running of the application.

For final production version it's best option to prepare [standalone version](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/ProductionDist) of your application.

Comment: @faisalabdulai that link explains everything, it **doesn't** demonstrate Play 2.0 with built-in Akka, but a module for Akka integration for **Play 1.x** by Dustin Whitney see: http://www.playframework.org/modules/akka. You need to pay more attention to filter tutorials targeted for Play 1.x and 2.x as they are quite other branches.